# how to pass extra custom attribute in Django template from "select option" form to a view

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have an html form include a select input in Django template, and the option has an extra attribute value called "testvalue".

I want to pass the "testvalue" attribute to my views.

Here is my example in Django HTML template:

```
<select  class="form-control select2" name="q_post_id"  >

    <option disabled selected >Select Post</option>

    {% for post in all_posts %}

        <option value="{{post.item.id}}" testvalue = "my test value" >  {{post.item.message}}</option>

    {% endfor %}

</select>
```

Normally in my view function I use the following code to get to input value:

```
q_post_id = request.POST.get("q_post_id")
```

but this will give me a default value `"{{post.item.id}}"`.

How can I get the extra custom attribute value in my view which is the 'testvalue '?

Comment: You don't. You should add this to the value, for example with `<option value="{{ post.item.pk}}-my test value">`, and then extract the two in the view.

Comment: but  i need it  as separated value key , i believe there is a solution for that .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select  class="form-control select2" name="q_post_id" id="q_post_id_select"  >
    <option disabled selected >Select Post</option>
    {% for post in all_posts %}
        <option value="{{post.item.id}}" data-testvalue = "my test value" >  {{post.item.message}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>

<input type="hidden" name="hiddenValue" id="hiddenOption">
```

Then in your js:

```
$('#q_post_id_select').on('change', function(e) {
  $('#hiddenOption').val( $(this).find(':selected').data('testvalue') );
});
```

Then after you make the request in django view:

```
testvalue = request.POST.get("hiddenValue")
```